# EF Core creates a duplication of a column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

As noted above I have a problem with EF Core. When I did the migration from Visual Studio, sql Management studio created a duplicate of a column

I have created three classes in a relationship and this relationship is always 1 to many

DbContext

```
 builder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasKey(C => new { C.Companykey, C.WorkerId });
        builder.Entity<Worker>()
            .HasKey(W => new { W.WorkerId });

        builder.Entity<Jobs>()
            .HasKey(J => new { J.CompanyKey, J.WorkerId, J.JobsKey });
```

The database creates two equal columns (WorkerId ) for the jobs class

The other great company and workers work wonderfully

```
public class Company
{
    public string Companykey { get; set; } //Pk

    public List<Jobs> Job { get; set; } = new List<Jobs>();

    public int WorkerId { get; set; } //PK FK
    public Worker? worker { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Worker 
{
    public int WorkerId { get; set; } //Pk
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public List<Company>? company { get; set; } = new List<Company>();
    public List<Job> Job { get; set; } = new List<Jobs>();
}

public class Jobs
{
  
    public string Companykey { get; set; } 
    public Company? company { get; set; } 

    public int WorkerId { get; set; } 
    public Worker? worker { get; set; }
    public string JobsKey { get; set; }       

}
```

Comment: You don't need to tell the EF by defining fluent API EF will take care of it. Removed this DbContext part fluentAPI then you will be good. Please also provide entities code as well if it is possible

Comment: Do you want the whole model code or just the Jobs class?

Comment: I want the whole model code

Comment: You don't need to define the fluentAPI your models are good to go. Please remove the dbContext code and run the migrations from the start it will create single column.